# Accessing Building blocks in Word Add-In Javascript API

Tags: javascript, ms-word, add-in

I'm developing Microsoft Word Add-In using javascript API. Is it possible to  list all Building Blocks(Content Controls) available in MS Word application to user and allow user to insert blocks in document ?

I've tried the solution provided here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8c4809c7-743c-4388-aef0-bc6a6855c882/office-2013-javascript-api-for-word-content-control-questions?forum=appsforoffice

I could not access Blocks at MS Word Application level.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to switch to VSTO word Add-In development from Javascript API. It works absolutely fine in VSTO as it provides very rich APIs for Word object model.